# Angular 2 ngStyle with browser prefixes

Tags: angular, angular2-security

This is not working:

```
<div [style.-moz-column-count]="columns"></div>
<div [ngStyle]="{'-moz-column-count': columns}"></div>
<div style="-moz-column-count: {{columns}}"></div>
```

Is there any workaround to avoid Sanitizer? I found a Pipe to bypass the value, but not the property name.

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({name: 'safe'})
export class SafePipe {
    constructor(sanitizer:DomSanitizationService){
        this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
    }

    transform(style) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    }
}
```

Any ideas to use this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write this like this:

```
this.style = {
  "MozColumnCount": 3,
  "column-count": 3,
}

<div [ngStyle]="style">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.  
</div>
```

Comment: More easily, this do NOT work: `this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.ele.nativeElement, '-moz-column-count', 5 )`

Comment: I tested this code in firefox 49 it does not work but in firedox developer edition the code indeed works. Must be firefox version issue

Comment: So your answer should be, `[style.column-count]="5"` works on developer edition. But I think it's not an issue cause doesn't work in previous version. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count#Browser_compatibility Unprefixed is not supported

Comment: Ohhhh!!! You can use CamelCase to avoid dashes... I didn't know that. Very good point!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with angular2 `ngStyle`.

You could go with `ngClass` option and scss like this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
    .columns-#{$i} {
        -webkit-column-count: #{$i};
        -moz-column-count: #{$i};
        column-count: #{$i};
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this but I'm looking for another solution.